# How to find subdirectory with highest index in its name?

Tags: bash, grep

So I'm having a little trouble with my grep statement as I basically have no idea how to do this.

As I understand everything in bash is a string, which is most unfortunate.

Anyway, what I have is a folder with a whole bunch of subfolder, something like this:

```
root_folder
  + sub_folder_1
  + sub_folder_2
  + sub_folder_3
  + sub_folder_4
```

How can I get the name of the subfolder with the highest index in its suffix? Or more specifically I'm more interested in the highest index, as I need to create a new subfolder with the next highest index.

I can get the list of subfolders with something like that, but then I'm lost:

`find ~/root_folder/sub_folder_* -maxdepth 1 -type d`

What I expect is a return value that only contains the currently highest index.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: `find . -type d -print | sort -u | tail -n1 | cut -d'_' -f3`

Comment: Thanks @0stone0, didn't do exactly what I wanted, but ended up doing it with `find ~/root_folder/sub_folder_* -maxdepth 1 -type d | sort -u | tail -n1 | rev | cut -d '_' -f1 | rev`

Comment: `echo root_folder/* | xargs -0 | sed -E 's/.*_([[:digit:]]*)$/\1/'`

Answer (score 0):

`find` is probably not ideal for this, it can find things and it can execute commands on the things it finds but it's not very good at comparing the things it finds to each other in arbitrary ways.

In bash you can use this:

```
#!/bin/bash
largest_index=0
for dir in ~/root_folder/sub_folder_* ; do # loop over all the sub_folder entries
  index="${dir##*_}" # deletes everything up to the last underscore
  if (( index > largest_index )) ; then
    largest_index="${index}" # store largest index found
  fi 
done
echo ~/root_folder/sub_folder_"${largest_index}" # this should match current highest
mkdir ~/root_folder/sub_folder_$(( largest_index + 1 )) # makes the next highest
```